# Easy_install issues

Tags: python, macos, easy-install

Trying to install easy_install (IRONIC) and it is not wanting to cooperate with me.
I am running the following command in terminal with python2.7

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -o - | python
returns me -->
-bash: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py: No such file or directory
```

is it a simple fix?

Comment: Is that on the command line or in a shell script (where the `#!/bin/sh` shebang may be missing)?

Comment: @tdelaney it is in command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -s | python
```

Unless redirected otherwise, cURL will output the received body to STDOUT, so you do not have to pass it `-o -` (which really should not do anything according to the docs). You should pass it `-s` in order to suppress the progress meter and any errors. Then pipe it directly into `python`. Given no other arguments, `python` will determine STDIN as the source of the script to execute.